# Get Max Sum value of a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv like this:

```
Country     Values  Address
USA         1       AnyAddress
USA         2       AnyAddress
Brazil      1       AnyAddress
UK          3       AnyAddress
Australia   0       AnyAddress
Australia   0       AnyAddress
```

I need to group data by Country and sum Values, then return a string with the country and max value summed, in this case considering USA that is lexicographically greater then UK, the output is like this:
`"Country: USA, Value: 3"`

When I use groupby in pandas I am not able to get the strings with country name and value, how can I do that?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
"I am not able" is not a problem specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
max_values = df.groupby('Country').sum().reset_index().max().values
your_string = f"Country: {max_values[0]}, Value: {max_values[1]}"
```

Output:

```
>>> print(your_string)
Country: USA, Value: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```py
df.groupby("Country", as_index=False)["Values"].sum()\
    .sort_values(["Values", "Country"], ascending=False).iloc[0]
```

Outputs:

```py
Country    USA
Values       3
Name: 3, dtype: object
```